# How to store a array in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I am trying to learn php databases and I have a question. How do I store an array in a database? I saw an answer on stackoverflow and there were they doing something with type `double` and in an other answer they were talking about creating a table for every user but I can't find a solution.

So summarized. I want to store an array in a database. I have acces to phpmyadmin so from there can I set the value type. and I would like to store that array in one column.

Can somebody help me solving the problem?

**edit one:** The things I want to store are music tags. So in code it would be something like this:

```
 array('pop','rock','country');
```

I want to store It in one column to make it easy searchable

Comment: Why would you want to store an array in one column?

Comment: You should first learn how to use databases before anything else. You shouldn't store an entire array in a single column but rather multiple columns.

Comment: the proper way will be using `json_encode` the array and than store it.

Comment: If that array is tags only you should save it by `implode(',',array('pop','rock','country'))`.

Comment: `json_encode()` / `json_decode()` is a valid option too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you shouldn't store arrays in a single column in a db. It is preferable to have a table with tags and another one that links your entity with its tags. So, before try to store an array in a table just think if it is really the right thing to do in your specific case (usually not).

If you are sure you want to do that then you have `serialize` and `unserialize` functions.

**UPDATE** (after five years)
`serialize` and `unserialize` methods are inherently unsecure and should be avoided. It is preferable to store data in `JSON` format using `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

Comment: But How can I link the tags in a table with a singer in an other table? Or is the solution complex

Comment: You use a third table that contains refs to the tag id and the singer id. Then you use `join` in your queries. It is a slight more complex, but this is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than storing arrays, try this:

Table 'genres' :

```
id | name
1  | pop
2  | rock
```

Table 'songs' :

```
id | ...
1
```

Table 'songs_genres' :

```
song_id | song_genre
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

And use JOIN's to get the genres for each song (or whatever)

Comment: @Vinc199789 This is actually the correct answer, `serialize` and `unserialize` shouldn't be used in your case as I, and a couple of other people, answered with before your usage example was added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is one option here. You can serialize a PHP array into a string to store in the database, and when you return the string from the database you can [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert it back from a string to an array.</strike>

**[ Edit ]**

After you've updated the question with an example of the data you plan to store, using a MANY:MANY relationship in the actual database structure is the correct way to go, as mentioned in @Alex M's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562169/1552160)

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode to make a json string from the array, like so :

```
    $jsonarray = json_encode($array);
```

then after retrieving the information you decode it.

```
    $array = json_decode($jsonarray, true); // the true will turn it into an array, 
    otherwise it's an object.
```

but I'd advice against it. try making a database which has the proper columns and store your data trough there.

Answer (score 0):

Every user can have one or more music tags. In later time they want to add or remove those tags. If you store all of their tags in one column you are pretty much left with string operation rather than database operation. create new table tbl_user_music_Tags and save each tag along with the user ID. this way you have full flexibility of adding, removing, updating and reading tags for a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as an string such as 'rock, pop, foo, ...'.
But if you want to manage tags, i think you should store tags in other table as @Alex M suggested.