# Storing arrays in database using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm currently building a project in which for every user I need to save a list of Strings (urls of articles he read).

I'm using python + flask + SQLalchemy with sqlite.

I understand that sqlite doesn't support arrays, so I was thinking about switching over to a different database instead of sqlite, one which supports arrays.

I would like to know what would you do? which database supports arrays or if there's better way solving it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing an Array of Strings in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584612/storing-an-array-of-strings-in-a-database)

Comment: [Also good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562036/how-to-store-a-array-in-a-database).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300230/using-list-as-a-data-type-in-a-column-sqlalchemy helped me best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialize it in some way. An option is to simply calling `str` with the array, and then handle it in some way when you need to convert it back.

Another option is to use the `json` module:

```py
import json


lst = [1,2,3]

serialized = json.dumps(lst)
print(serialized)                           # '[1, 2, 3]'
print(type(serialized))                     # <class 'str'>

deserialized = json.loads(serialized)
print(deserialized)                         # [1, 2, 3]
print(type(deserialized))                   # <class 'list'>
```

But as ggorlen's link suggests, you should try to come up with a better option than storing the array directly.

Comment: On both links I see the serialized option, which I would need to learn because I'm not familiar with. Does it have any disadvantages?

Comment: @DanielSegal Are you familiar with [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)? Atomicity is a requirement for [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). But serialization is simply to convert data to a format that can be stored (e.g. a string).

Comment: No, Im not familiar with it. my question is is this method different from doing str(list) and when I want to go back to list just write a fancy function which does it?

Comment: Both are methods of stringifying an object, but `str` is valid Python, `json.dumps` is valid JSON and Python. But yes, you can definitely write a fancy function that converts back. I just think it's easier to use `json.loads` instead.

Comment: Also, SQLite supports [adaptation of objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases).

Comment: SQLite also supports JSON, and SQLAlchemy supports SQLite JSON implementation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.JSON

Answer (score 5):

MySQL and SQLlite both have support for JSON columns. You can store an array in a JSON column. In terms of best practice and performance, putting arrays in a database is debatable of course.

ORM

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    list_of_items = Column(JSON, nullabled=False)
```

Adding an Array to your DB.

```
parent_one = Parent(list_of_items=['item1', 'item2'])
session.add(parent_one)
session.commit()
```

Now when you fetch the record of parent_one, you will see its 'list_of_items' column is an array in python.

This can also be done with the SQL alchemy core language.